# Django project will not load in CSS files

Tags: python, css, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently directly following the tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDwdMDQ8oX4
about setting up a blog website through Django. When I attempt to load in my CSS files, I obtain the same screen that the person in the video was achieving @38:01, when he claims the css wasn't loading in (I have restarted my server many times so that isn't the issue). For reference it should look like the screen @38:51 No colors and the header bar is mixed with the page header. I am able to open up the css through the source code on the browser, so it must be being referenced correctly; however here is my relevant code:

to reference the static files in settings.py (Note I had it exactly like how it is in the video and changed it to this with no change):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_files')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

the attempt to use the css file as a stylesheet:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

     <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stytlesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">
```

[My project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXapt.png)

Also I guess here is the css code if it is any help:

````
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #333333;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: #00FBF9;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-steel {
  background-color: #5f788a;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #cbd5db;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.content-section {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.article-title {
  color: #444444;
}

a.article-title:hover {
  color: #428bca;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-content {
  white-space: pre-line;
}

.article-img {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.article-metadata {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3
}

.article-metadata a:hover {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.account-img {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.account-heading {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}```
````

Comment: Did you launch the command `python manage.py collectstatic` ?

Answer (score 0):

comment out `STATIC_ROOT = 'static'` and add the below code to your settings.py file.

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

If still not work then run this command on terminal

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

for reference go through official Django documentation [django static configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#module-django.contrib.staticfiles) , [django documentation](https://www.djangoproject.com/). It's good for those who are new to django.

Comment: I tried that and got the error: 

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\brade\\PycharmProjects\\SpotifyWeb\\static'

When I made the line in settings.py:
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'blog/static'),)

I get the error:

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

Comment: Just create a directory in project root with static name. It will work.